# Stability of an unstable system using nonlinear element. Is it possible or not?

Tags: control-systems

Say there is a system with open-loop transfer function
G(s)=1/(s−1)
. The system is definitely unstable.

If I put any nonlinear system in cascade with G(s) and from the output, a negative unity feedback. Is it possible to make the system close-loop transfer function is stable? It is assumed that the higher order harmonics are filtered in the close loop path.
electrical-engineering

Comment: There is no closed-loop transfer function, because due the non-linear element the total system cannot be described by a transfer function any longer.

Comment: [Cross-post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/159670/stability-of-an-unstable-system-using-nonlinear-element-is-it-possible-or-not) from electronics.SE.

Comment: You can do that with a linear element (a single gain will work), why use nonlinear element?